# Add jquery mobile draggable button at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am building jquery mobile prototyping. I want to add button in it at runtime that should be draggable and resizeable. It works well when I have added button manually in the code but not dynamically. Anyone please help :(

Dynamic Code:
 $("#myframe").contents().find("#drag").append(' Dynamic');

Mobile Content Tag:

Button1

Jquery Draggable:

$(".draggable").draggable();

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: If you put up jsfiddle of your attempt at dynamically adding the button, I'll take a look in a few hours..

Answer (score 0):

try this :

After you insert your button dynamically, recreate the page...

```
$("div[data-role='page']").page('destroy').page();
```

Last time I had faced the similar problem. I solved it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent shown your code, we can only guess

have you considered using jquery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ?

Comment: it is used for attaching event handlers to dynamically added elements in jquery. Please read more on the link I provided

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vjGmt/

Code:

```
$('<a>').data('role','button').attr({'href':'#', 'id':'test-button'}).html('Dynamic button').button().appendTo('[data-role="content"]');
$('#test-button').draggable();
```